# How to write an ID attribute to another node

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm new in XSLT and I don't know how I can transform this:

```
   <GCInitialStep id="id_A" name="INIT"/>
   <GCTransition id="id_B" name="T1"/>
   <GCStep id="id_C" name="A1"/>
   <!-- ... -->
   <GCLink fromObject="id_A" toObject="id_B"/>  
   <GCLink fromObject="id_B" toObject="id_C"/>
```

To

```
   <InitialStep id="id_A" name="INIT"
                parentid=""
                childid="id_B"/>
   <Transition id="id_B" name="T1"
               parentid="id_A"
               childid="id_C"/>
   <Action id="id_C" name="A1"
         parentid="id_B"
         childid=""/>
```

Is it possible? How?

Thanks :)

Comment: I just edited question, in input, `GCLink` links the objects by their ID and I want to consolide this in the node by specifying parent/child (if any).

Comment: You need to explain the requirements! For example: What are the rules for generating an `Action` element? Please, edit the question and provide a complete XML document (what you have now is not a well-formed document), the exact wanted result and a good explanation of all requirements that the transformation must implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:key name="fromKey" match="GCLink" use="@fromObject"/>
    <xsl:key name="toKey" match="GCLink" use="@toObject"/>

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::GCLink)]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{substring(name(), 3)}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="@id"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@name"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="parentid">
                <xsl:value-of select="key('toKey', @id)/@fromObject"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="childid">
                <xsl:value-of select="key('fromKey', @id)/@toObject"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

applied to

```
<root>
    <GCInitialStep id="id_A" name="INIT"/>
    <GCTransition id="id_B" name="T1"/>
    <GCStep id="id_C" name="A1"/>
    <GCLink fromObject="id_A" toObject="id_B"/>
    <GCLink fromObject="id_B" toObject="id_C"/>
</root>
```

outputs

```
<root>
  <InitialStep id="id_A" name="INIT" parentid="" childid="id_B" />
  <Transition id="id_B" name="T1" parentid="id_A" childid="id_C" />
  <Step id="id_C" name="A1" parentid="id_B" childid="" />
</root>
```